# How to reuse method when return in back to activity in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a method in an activity, I am using this method in onCreate in that activity.
My question is , how to make my activity to reuse that method when I open that activity by pressing back from another activity?

Comment: Override `onResume()` function and call the function on `onResume()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the method in `onResume()` of your Activity. It will get called when ever you will get back to your Activity from another Activity. Remove the call from `onCreate()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same method, it's better to call it in the `onResume()` callback instead of `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have one `FeatureActivityA` and `FeatureActivityB`,and now `FeatureActivityA` has a method named `handleSomeAction()`.I guess you want to use `handleSomeAction` in your `FeatureActivityB`,so my solution is define a base activity for your `FeatureActivityA` and `FeatureActivityB`,we named it as `BaseActivity` ,some code will as following:

```
BaseActivity extends Activity{
    void handleSomeAction(){
       //do something
    }
}
```

`FeatureActivityA`'s code will like:

```
FeatureActivityA extends BaseActivity{
    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       handleSomeAction();
    }
}
```

`FeatureActivityA`'s code will like:

```
FeatureActivityB extends BaseActivity{
    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       handleSomeAction();
    }
}
```

Hope that can help you.